# Database connection test fails in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I am trying to create strapi project but i get this error after entering the database details:

```
?? Connection test failed: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\CREATI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\strapi055848bdd5ae\node_modules\strapi-connector-bookshelf\lib\utils\connectivity.js'
```

Here is the command I used: `npx create-strapi-app my-project` & `yarn create strapi-app my-project`

I want to use `Posgres`, but I tried with `MySQL` also, and it throws the same error. Moreover I tried creating project both with npx and yarn and got same error. Although, it works fine with the `--quickstart` flag.

Node version: 12
NPM version: 6

What is this about? How to solve it?

Comment: Can you share your database config file

Comment: @NS23 The error occurs before the project is even created. The error is from cli output when I choose `custom` and not `quickstart`.